# Show only specifics formats in the photoPicker

Tags: android

I would like to show a photoPicker but only with specifics format of images (png and jpeg).

For the moment I have this :

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

It work but I have all the images format in the photoPicker.

Can I change the `setType()` to something like this : `setType("png, jpeg")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Or you can use the onActivityResult to check the file using :

```
filePath.endsWith(".jpeg")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/jpeg, image/png");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

I use the MIME type that I can set in setType() like :

- image/png
- image/jpeg
- image/gif